# Android Pay Wallet.Payments.isReadyToPay method is returning false

Tags: android, android-pay

I have gone through the following guidelines to test Android Pay Sample Application. However i am always getting false result in response of method call Wallet.Payments.isReadyToPay().

https://developers.google.com/android-pay/android/quickstart#next_steps
https://developers.google.com/android-pay/android/tutorial#obtain_credentials_and_a_client_id_for_your_app

You can check out the source code of application from below link
https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart

As it appears it is using Wallet APIs as per my knoweldge,so is it possible that if my phone doesnt have Google Wallet application installed which is causing false response?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to have AndroidPay installed with a valid CC on file in the application.

Also as you're testing, if you leave the pre-auth checkbox checked on the AndroidPay chooser dialog. You can remove the pre-auth behavior so it will prompt every time by going to settings/google/connected_apps and disconnecting your application. If Google is not a section in your system settings then you might have a separate "Google Settings" app.